# PHP RegExp: Capture all HTML closing tags followed by new line character

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture any HTML closing tags that are followed by a newline character and replace them by only the HTML tag.

For example I want to turn this:

```
<ul>\n
    <li>element</li>\n
</ul>\n\n
<br/>\n\n
Some text\n
```

into this:

```
<ul>
    <li>element</li>
</ul>\n
<br/>\n
Some text\n
```

The problem is that I cannot capture `\n` characters with regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(<\/[a-zA-Z]*>|<[a-zA-Z]*\/>)\n/s', $in, $matches);
```

As soon I place the \n somewhere in my pattern the matches array will return empty values.

Interesting thing that if I try to match the `\n` character standalone only, it finds all of them:

```
preg_match_all('/\n/s', $in, $matches);
```

Comment: So you want to replace `\n\n` with `\n`? Matching alone isn't going to replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
preg_match_all('/(<\/[a-zA-Z]*>|<[a-zA-Z]*\/>)\\n/s', $in, $matches);
```

You have to escape the "\" character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
(<[^>]+>)$\R{2}
# capture anything between a pair of < and > at the end of the line
# followed by two newline characters
```

You'll need to use the `multiline` mode, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dG9eS8/2).
In `PHP` this would be:

```
$regex = '~(<[^>]+>)$\R{2}~m';
$string = preg_replace($regex, "$1", $your_string_here);
```

Generally, the `DomDocument` parser offers the possibility to preserve or throw away whitespaces, so you might be better of using this instead.